# Is there a way to specify terraform plugins directory for terratest?

Tags: terratest

and thanks in advance.

I have a practical question about terratest, 
with terraform I can do this:

`terraform init -backend-config /tmp/provider.tfvars.json -plugin-dir /opt/terra_plugins`

such as, terraform leaves our company proxy alone, and does not download the plugins million times a day (we have a docker build script thingy, so we build terraform env releases into docker). All in all I would like to make the same with terratest - first surprise was that even if I do terraform init before, terratest seems to use some other way than .terraform directory, it does not get the things from there - shall I aim to change this behaviour?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`terratest` has the ability to specify [`Options`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest@v0.28.10/modules/terraform?tab=doc#Options). This includes `BackendConfig`. `-plugin-dir` is not included, but the included `EnvVars` can use the terraform [`TF_CLI_ARGS`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/environment-variables.html#tf_cli_args-and-tf_cli_args_name) environment variable to specify the `-plugin-dir` option.